# Python 3 verification script not checking properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a python script and am having issues with some verification's I set up. I have this procedure file that has a function that uses a order number and a customer number to check some past history about the customers orders. Ive been testing live on our server and I keep failing the last if statement. The order number and customer number Im using does have more than one order and some are over 60 days so it should pass the test but it doesnt. Ive been looking over my code and I just cant see what could be causing this

edit: here are the print results of current and retrieved timestamps:

```
current_timestamp = 1531849617.921927 
retrieved_timestamp = 1489622400 
two_month_seconds   = 5184000
one_month_seconds   = 2592000
```

Python3

```
from classes import helper
from classes import api
from classes import order
from procedures import orderReleaseProcedure
import time
import datetime
import re

def verifyCustomer(customer_id, order_id):
    self_helper              = helper.Helper()
    customer_blocked_reasons = self_helper.getConfig('customer_blocked_reasons')
    order_statuses           = self_helper.getConfig('order_statuses')
    customer_is_blocked      = False
    self_api                 = api.Api()
    self_order               =order.Order(order_id)
    status                   = {
                                 'success' : 0,
                                 'message' :'verify_payment_method'
                               }
    results                  = self_api.which_api('orders?customer_id={}'.format(customer_id))
    order_count              = results['total_count']   

    if order_count > 1:
      for result in results['orders']:
          order_status_info= self_api.which_api('order_statuses/%d' % result['order_status_id'])
          for customer_blocked_reason in customer_blocked_reasons:
            if customer_blocked_reason in order_status_info['name']:
              customer_is_blocked = True

          order_id            = 0
          order_date          = result['ordered_at']
          two_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 60
          one_month_seconds   = (3600 * 24) * 30
          stripped_date       = order_date[:order_date.find("T")]
          current_timestamp   = time.time()
          retrieved_timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(stripped_date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%s"))

          if retrieved_timestamp > (current_timestamp - one_month_seconds) and not customer_is_blocked: 
            status['success'] = 1
            status['message'] = "Customer Verified with orders older than 30 days and no blocking reasons" 
            print(' 30 day check was triggered ')         
            print(status)
            break

          elif customer_is_blocked:
            status_change_result = self_order.update_status(order_statuses['order_hold_manager_review'])
            status['success']    = 1
            status['message']    = "Changed order status to Order Hold - Manager Review" 

            print(' Customer block was triggered ')
            print(status_change_result)
            break

          elif not retrieved_timestamp <  (current_timestamp - two_month_seconds):          
            status['success'] = 0
            status['message'] = "There is more than 1 order, and none are greater than 60 days, we need to check manually" 

            print(' 60 day check was triggered ')
            print(status)
            break

    return status
```

Comment: Can you print retrieved_timestamp and current_timestamp please right before the ifs?
Also `time.time()` is float and your `retrieved_timestamp` is int.

I think you must convert your datetime to unix timestamp accordingly.

Comment: current_timestamp = 1531849617.921927
retrieved_timestamp = 1489622400

Comment: Should it be `retrieved_timestamp < (current_timestamp - one_month_seconds)` in the first `if`? If it is older the time stamp is **smaller**. The condition does not match the description in `message`...

Comment: `Current timestamp = GMT: Tuesday, 17 July 2018 17:46:57`
`Retreived timestamp is = GMT: Thursday, 16 March 2017 00:00:00`

So theoretically it should be working... Can you print the output of `two_month_seconds`? Cuz i think that might be the problem

Comment: Anyway, I'd personally avoid using timestamps here. Just use `a = datetime.now().date()` and `b = datetime.strptime(order_date, '%Y-%m-%dT<whatever-format>").date()` then `(a-b).total_seconds() > one_month_seconds` etc. Much clearer.

Comment: I added both one and two months outputs

Comment: two_month_seconds   = 5184000
one_month_seconds   = 2592000